# 'hbase shell' TypeError: can't convert Pathname into String while starting

Tags: java, ruby, shell, hbase, bigdata

I am logged into a Linux machine via ssh where HBase is installed. Whenever I try to start the HBase shell, I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert Pathname into String
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071
  require at file:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:118
```

Result of `hbase version`:

```
util.VersionInfo: HBase 1.0.0-cdh5.4.2
```

Result of java  -version:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
```

Unfortunately, it's a remotely hosted application so I am not aware of the installation details of it. Do I need to pass some parameters while starting the shell? If so, what are the ways of doing that?

Comment: Probably problem in the configuration file. Do you define paths there?